# Rxjs bindNodeCallback is not working properly with swithmap and flatmap

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs

I'm trying to read files by using bindNodeCallback and fs readdir, stat.

Here's my code:

```
import { readdir, stat, Stats } from "fs";
import { bindNodeCallback, Observable, of } from "rxjs";
import { catchError, filter, flatMap, map, mergeMap, switchMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const readDirBindCallback: (path: string) => Observable<string[]> = bindNodeCallback(readdir);
const fileStateBindCallback: (path: string) => Observable<Stats> = bindNodeCallback(stat);

readDirBindCallback('/Users/.../WebstormProjects/copy')
    .pipe(
        flatMap(x => x),
        tap(console.log),
        switchMap(status => {
            console.log(status);
            return fileStateBindCallback('/Users/.../WebstormProjects/copy/' + status);
        })
    )
    .subscribe(result => {
        console.log(result)
    });
```

"switchMap" has been called multiple times correctly.

The problem is fileStateBindCallback has been called only once, the final subscibe logged only once.

Why is this happened? 
If I subscribe the fileStateBindCallback manually in switchMap block. It would run as I expect. But that is not a good pratice and not fit in my request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the `switchMap` operator.

`switchMap` can only have one active inner observable at a time. If an outer values comes in and there is an active inner obs., it will be unsubscribed and a new one will be **created** based on the **newly arrived value** and the **provided function** to `switchMap`.

`readdir` will return an `array`.

`flatMap(arr => arr)` will simply emit the array's items **separately** and **synchronously**.

Let's assume your directory has `N` items.

`flatMap` will emits these items one by one. 
So `item 1` is passed along and `switchMap` will create an inner obs (`fileStateBindCallback`), which involves asynchronous operation.
Then, `item 2` is sent, but as this happens synchronously, the current inner observable(that one created due to `item 1`) handled by `switchMap` will be unsubscribed and a new one will be created for `item 2`.

And so forth, until `item N` finally arrives. Remember that the array's items are emitted synchronously. The `item N-1`'s inner obs. will be unsubscribed and a new one will be created for `item N`. But since `N` is the last item in the array, it can't be interrupted by any subsequent emissions, meaning that its inner observable will have the time to emit & complete.

What you might be looking for is `concatMap`.

When `N`th item arrives, it will **wait** for the current inner observable created due to the `N-1`th item to **complete**, before creating a **new** one based on the `N`th item.

So, replacing `switchMap` with `concatMap` should do the job. If the order is not important, you can opt for `mergeMap`.

Comment: Thx, Andrei. Ur answer inspire me. I haven't notice the async calling in the switchMap.I used to use it with sync method and that worked fine as the order. Appriciate.